# como seleccionar un elemento de un ng-repeat por codigo

Tags: html, angularjs

amigos necesito porf avor me ayuden con lo siguiente,

```html
<select ng-model="estructura.organiza.superior" class="form-control" required>
 <option ng-repeat="puesto in Puestos" selected="{{sup}}"
    value="{{puesto.value}}">
  {{puesto.title}}
 </option>
 </select>
```

y necesito que muestre un elemento de la lista especifico, en el $scope.sup ya tengo el value como puedo lograrlo, el comportamiento es raro ya que aveces muestra el elemnto correcto y aveces de nada muestra el primer elemento de la lista

Comment: Coloca tu arreglo ... o lo  que contiene tu objeto Puestos

Comment: es incorrecta la logica que estas implementando. para asignar una opcion de tu select deberias validar si sup == a algo.. capaz que si puesto.X == sup ahi le asignas a esa opcion el atributo selected. explica con mas detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mi arreglo es una lista de una consulta a la base, para el caso da igual con cualquier tipo de arreglo, buscando encontre la solución:

```html
<select ng-model="estructura.organiza.superior" class="form-control" required>
          <option ng-repeat="puesto in Puestos" ng-selected="{{puesto.value==sup}}"
            value="{{puesto.value}}">
            {{puesto.title}}
          </option>
         </select>
```

la lógica iba por ahi pero la sintaxis o era la adecuada, ahora si funciona perfecto por sia lguien le sirva, asludos